# App Store Connect Operation Error: Missing CFBundleIdentifier in path

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm currently trying to "revive" an old project, but I'm stuck at uploading it to itunes Connect.
This is what I get when trying to upload the archive.
I'm using Xcode 10.0

[image]

Solved it. Had to add `Bundle OS Type code` and value `APPL` in the .plist file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding **Bundle OS Type code** and value APPL in the .plist file  worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify info.plist exists on the project.
2. Navigate to build settings and verify a 'product bundle identifier is present.

Comment: `product bundle identifier` is present in the target's build settings. Also the info.plist exists in the project.